# Spring Integration Java DSL unit test - How to mock a Service Activator class or other components/endpoints?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-integration, dsl

I have a class which contains a few service activator methods as follows:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class TestService {
    @ServiceActivator
    public void setComplete(Message<String> message){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

In the integration flow, one of the channels call one of these methods:

```
@Bean
public TestService testService() {
    return new TestService();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
            .handle("testService", "setComplete")
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}
```

I'm writing a unit test for this flow and using Mockito for mcoking the service activator class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class AppTest {

    @Mock
    private TheGateway startGateway;

    @Mock
    private TestService testrvice;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testChannel")
    DirectChannel testChannel;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test()
    public void testMessageProducerFlow() throws Exception {

        Mockito.doNothing().when(startGateway).execute("test");
        startGateway.execute("test");
        Mockito.verify(startGateway).execute("test");
        TestChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("test"));
        Mockito.verify(testService).setComplete(new GenericMessage<>("test"));

    }
}
```

When I don't mock the TestService, it executes the flow without issues.
Any guideance on how to Mock the Service activator class would be helpful.

**UPDATE:**
When I mock it (as shown in snippet above), it does not call the mocked object, instead executes the actual stuff, and the last line `Mockito.verify(testService)...` asserts that the mock testService was never called.

Comment: What is the issue if you mock it? Would be helpful if you could share that as well.

Comment: @hrrgttnchml - Updated my question with the requested information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you misunderstood how Spring Test Framework works.

1. `@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationConfig.class)` loads the config as is without any modification and start an application context based on that config.
2. According to the first condition your `.handle("testService", "setComplete")` uses `testService()` `@Bean` not `@Mock`
3. Only after the test applicationContext startup all those `@Mock`s and `@Autowired`s start working.

In other words your mocking doesn't change anything in the original `IntegrationConfig`.

In the Framework with use reflection to retrieve some field of the particular bean to replace it with the mock. But it isn't so easy way.

I suggest you to distinguish the Integration and Service configuration and use two different classes for production and for testing. Something like this:

1. The `testService()` `@Bean` must be moved from the `IntegrationConfig` to the new `@Configuration` class for production.
2. The `TestServiceConfig` may look like this:

   ```
   @Bean
   public TestService testService() {
       return Mockito.mock(new TestService());
   }
   ```
3. And finally your `AppTest` should be modified like this:

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {IntegrationConfig.class, TestServiceConfig.class})
   ....
   @Autowired
   private TestService testrvice;
   ```

That's everything is just because the application context and unit test scopes are on the different levels.

Comment: Great, that worked. However, the Mock throws error at this `Mockito.verify(testService).setComplete(new GenericMessage<>("test"));` .. `"Actual invocation has different arguments"` ... Any Thoughts on this? Is this expected?

Comment: For now, I've stubbed the verification with Mockito.any().

Comment: Yes, that's correct (`"Actual invocation has different arguments"`). Just because `GenericMessage` is **immutable** object and a `new` one won't be equal to the old one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution